# Как сделать мультиязычность на laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Подскажите, как сделать мультиязычность на сайте.

Если я все правильно поняла, нужно сделать подгрузку модуля с Laravel, и клик привязать к Vue?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/localization#introduction

https://laravel-news.com/laravel-localization-vue-package